# When will Natty dailies have final 2.6.38 kernel in them?

Tags: 11.04, kernel

I see that the [2.6.38 kernel has just come out](http://www.osnews.com/story/24526/Linux_2_6_38_Released). I have also read that [this kernel will be in Natty](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/601299/comments/37) when it comes out.

At what point will the Natty dailies have this final version of the kernel in them? Perhaps they already do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It already is in Natty](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/natty-changes/2011-March/009413.html). You can check the version of the linux source package (which contains the kernel) [on Launchpad here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux). From there the 'View full change log' link will show you what's changed over time.

Comment: I've never looked at this page before - thanks! However, it seems to suggest to me that 2.6.38-7.35 was added "14 hours ago" (at the time of writing) and that "A newer version of linux is available for packaging: Linux 2.6.38-rc8". I'm looking for the final release, which I think came out between Monday and Tuesday of this week. Do I just keep watching this page until I see that the 2.6.38 final version has been packaged, and then download the following day's nightly build?

Comment: I think that 'newer version' stuff isn't very accurate here—the kernel team uses funny version numbers that I don't quite understand, but the important part is in the changelog I linked to: "rebase from v2.6.38-rc8 to v2.6.38 final". Anyway, there's a reason they aren't in Natty yet — they are stuck in the NEW queue (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+queue?queue_state=0&queue_text=linux). This means that the new packages are waiting to be accepted by an archive administrator. When they disappear from this queue they'll be available to download and will thereafter appear on the dailies. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes , Linux kernel 2.6.38 already in Ubuntu Natty .